# Excel macros generating geometric distribution without zero

Tags: excel, vba

I need to generate geometric distribution values without zero with excel. I have one code, but that code gives me geometric distribution values with 0.

Can anyone help me with this code?

```
Function GEOMRAND() 'ByVal Beta As Double
    Beta = Cells(2, 2)
    Dim K As Double
    Dim Upper As Double
    Dim Lower As Double
    Upper = 1 - Rnd
    Lower = 1 - Beta
    K = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(Upper / Lower) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(Lower)
    If K < 0 Then
        K = 0
    End If
    GEOMRAND = Round(K, 0)
End Function

Function GEOMINV(ByVal R As Double, ByVal B As Double) 'ByVal Beta As Double
    Dim Upper As Double
    Dim Lower As Double
    Upper = 1 - R
    Lower = 1 - B
    K = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(Upper / Lower) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(Lower)
    If K <= 0 Then
        K = 0
    End If
    GEOMINV = Round(K, 0)
End Function

Sub GEOMGEN(ByVal Col As Integer)
    For i = 1 To 30
        For j = 1 To Col
            Cells(j + 10, i) = GEOMRAND()
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub GEOMFILL()
    Worksheets("G_500").Select
    GEOMGEN (500)
    Worksheets("G_2000").Select
    GEOMGEN (2000)
    Worksheets("G_8000").Select
    GEOMGEN (8000)
    Worksheets("G_32000").Select
    GEOMGEN (32000)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for some values you explicitly tell excel to return 0.

You should change the If lines to set the value to something other than zero when K<0 or K<=0.